# Painting app for iphone

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am trying to develop a painting application which allows the user to draw/paint over an image by selecting different colored brushes.I tried to implement this by subclassing uiimageview and override the following methods :

```
 - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];


    lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    //  lastPoint.y -=20;// only if signature goes bottom of the screen
}


- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    //  currentPoint.y -=20; // only if signature goes bottom of the screen


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);

    CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(currentContext, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(currentContext, 15.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(currentContext, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextBeginPath(currentContext);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(currentContext, lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(currentContext, currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(currentContext);
    self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    lastPoint = currentPoint;
}
```

But the issue here is that ,if the user draws over  the borderline of the image then the color hides the border line .I need to make the borderline visible even if the user draws over the border line also.Is it possible to do that or do i need to go forward with any openGL techniques.Please share your comments..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2106/core-graphics-101-arcs-and-paths  i am not very sure if this is what u r looking for ,but in this link CGContextClip() is explained which limits the drawing to a particular region

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `UIView` subclass that contains only the border and add it on top of your current view.
You will only have to return No in `pointInside: withEvent:` method to transfer touches to the view underneath it.

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    return NO;
}
```